# Geocode returning wrong lat/long

Tags: python, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am using this code to geocode this address to get the lat and long, but it is returning the wrong coordinates.

```
import requests
address = '50 Bega St, Tathra NSW 2550, Australia'
response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address= address &key= ****')

resp_json_payload = response.json()

print(resp_json_payload)
print(resp_json_payload['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])
```

Expected result: -36.730478 149.985058

Actual Result: 'lat': 37.09024, 'lng': -95.712891

Comment: Maybe you could click `edit` and add the json payload too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Code compiled on Python 3.6, you might want to use a different url parsing library for older version of Python.

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
address = '50 Bega St, Tathra NSW 2550, Australia'
api_key = 'your_api_key'
encoded_address = urllib.parse.quote(address)
response = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+encoded_address+'&key='+api_key)

resp_json_payload = response.json()

print(resp_json_payload)
print(resp_json_payload['results'][0]['geometry']['location'])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello @vartika , if it works for you, please vote (up vote) the solution using the arrows to the left of the comment.